# Setting a custom scale for the first three frames of a video in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am looking for setting a custom scale for my first three frames of a video, with ffmpeg.

My video is an image loop, that lasts 5 seconds, 10 frames per second. For this, I use:

```
ffmpeg -r 10 -loop 1 -i myimage.jpg -t 5 out.mp4
```

I tried setting a different brightness for my first three frames, and I got it working with this command:

```
ffmpeg -r 10 -loop 1 -i background.jpg -filter_complex eq=brightness=eq(n\,0)*1.2+eq(n\,1)*0.5+eq(n\,2)*4.5:eval=frame -t 5 out.mp4
```

But I can't get it working for scales. I tried with scale=size and other stuff I can find in [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg%20documentation), but nothing worked for me.

If you have any hint, let me know! Thanks.

EDIT: Here are more details:
I'm looking to scale up or down an image, but not going under its default scale.
My PNG scale is 100% by default, I should go to 110%, and then 108% right after for example, but I don't need to go under 100%.

In a context:
I want a 1920x1080 video.
In this 1920x1080 video, if I want frame 1 to be 100% scale, frame 2 110% and frame 3 105%:

```
Frame 1: 1920x1080
Frame 2: 2112x1188 (cropped at 1920x1080)
Frame 3: 2016x1134 (cropped at 1920x1080)
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you mean scale up or scale down? Since all the video frames have to be the same resolution... with up-scaling, we have to crop the center, and with down-scaling we have to pad the margins. You may also consider using `zoompan` filter. What is the resolution of the input? What are the scaling parameters?

Comment: I didn't even thought about cropping, I was just thinking there was a basic scale filter. I will look into zoompan filter! I also added context to my post, hope this is more detailed now! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We may use [zoompan](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/zoompan.htm.gz1) filter as follows:

`ffmpeg -y -r 10 -loop 1 -i myimage.jpg -vf zoompan=z='eq(in\,0)*1+eq(in\,1)*1.1+eq(in\,2)*1.05+gte(in\,3)*1':d=1:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':fps=10:s=1920x1080 -t 10 out.mp4`

The `eq(in\,0)*1+eq(in\,1)*1.1+eq(in\,2)*1.05+gte(in\,3)*1` expression is kind of programming...

---

`z='eq(in\,0)*1+eq(in\,1)*1.1+eq(in\,2)*1.05+gte(in\,3)*1` expression description:

- `eq(in\,0)*1` - value of `eq(in,0)` is `1` for the first frame and `0` for other frames.
  Value of `eq(in,0)*1` is `1` for the first frame and `0` for other frames.
- `eq(in\,1)*1.1` - value of `eq(in,1)` is `1` for the second frame and `0` for other frames.
  Value of `eq(in,0)*1.1` is `1.1` for the first frame and `0` for other frames.
- `eq(in\,2)*1.05` equals `1.05` for the third frame and `0` for other frames.
- `gte(in\,3)*1` equals `0` for the first 3 frames, and `1` for other frames.

The sum of the above expressions is: `1.0` for frame #0, `1.1` for frame #1, `1.05` for frame #2 and `1.0` for frame #3.

`x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)` centers the image (as in [zoompan example](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/zoompan.htm.gz1)).

---

Example of 192x108 image at 1Hz:

Build synthetic image (for testing):

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=1 myimage.png`

Apply zoom for the first 3 frames:

`ffmpeg -y -r 1 -loop 1 -i myimage.png -vf zoompan=z='eq(in\,0)*1+eq(in\,1)*1.1+eq(in\,2)*1.05+gte(in\,3)*1':d=1:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':fps=1:s=192x108 -t 10 out.mp4`

---

First image (zoom = 1):
[image]

Second image (zoom = 1.1):
[image]

Third image (zoom = 1.05):
[image]

Fourth image (zoom = 1):
[image]